# How do I make the PendingIntent trigger my GeofenceBroadcastReceirver?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-geofence

So, I am making use of Geofences in my app. I have tree locations on a GoogleMaps map and all three are geofences.

So far they are successfully built and added to my app but no trigger is activated when I enter the geofence area.

Location permissions are working so I assume it is not a problem from them therefore I am not posting them.

I am following the official tutorial from the android documentation - [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing)

Why is the trigger not working?

Here is my code:

**OnCreate()**

```
geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this)

        GeofencingConstants.BookPlaces_DATA.forEach {
            geofenceList.add(Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId(it.name)

                // Set the circular region of this geofence.
                .setCircularRegion(
                    it.latLng!!.latitude,
                    it.latLng!!.longitude,
                    GeofencingConstants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                )

                // Set the expiration duration of the geofence. This geofence gets automatically
                // removed after this period of time.
                .setExpirationDuration(GeofencingConstants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)

                // Set the transition types of interest. Alerts are only generated for these
                // transition. We track entry and exit transitions in this sample.
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)

                // Create the geofence.
                .build())
        }
```

**Request**

```
     private fun getGeofencingRequest(): GeofencingRequest {
            return GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
                setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
                addGeofences(geofenceList)
            }.build()
        }
```

**Intent**..does not trigger the receiver

```
      private val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
            val intent = Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
            // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling
            // addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        }
```

**Add geofences**

```
     private fun addGeofencesToClient(){
            geofencingClient?.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), geofencePendingIntent)?.run {
                addOnSuccessListener {
                    // Geofences added
                    // ...
                    Log.i("added","GEOFENCES ADDED")
                    Toast.makeText(this@MapsActivity, R.string.geofences_added,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
                addOnFailureListener {
                    // Failed to add geofences
                    // ...
                    println(it.localizedMessage)
                    Log.i("failed","NOT ADDED")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Fiphe, did you create JobIntentService.

Comment: Hey, I just figured it out. It is actually working. I have to open google maps on the emulator otherwise it does not get my location.

Comment: First you should implement LocationListener. Then you can use fake location app or send new location to emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually working. What I needed to do is to open GoogleMaps on the emulator because apparently it needs so to get your location.